# Trouble turning off supply valve - need it shut off but won’t fully close

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I am attempting to install a bidet attachment I ordered online. The first step is to shut off the supply valve and empty the toilet, as it attaches on between the supply valve and tank.

I am unable to fully shut off the water supply. The supply valve opens fully and it will stifle the supply water somewhat but not completely off it. I am afraid to force it or use a tool with my level of plumbing knowledge. Could any helpful people give me advice on a course of action? I see a screw on top of the valve— I’m deathly afraid of losing some piece of it and flooding the bathroom. As much as I can hand turn it, it just isn’t enough to cut off the supply to do the work needed.

I could shut off the entire house water supply if all else fails but I’d like to be able to turn off the water supply valve locally.

[image: The supply valve]

[image: supply valve view other side]

Comment: Looks like a 1/4 turn valve. There's no forcing those, so don't. Always know where the main shut off is before doing anything.

Comment: Typical inexpensive consumer valve ; replace it as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Getting it to shut off completely is unnecessary. There are plenty of SE questions about swapping a valve or trying to get it to close more if you *really* want to. You're talking about a down time of minutes, not days or weeks; that's when I would suggest that, or taking it off and capping it.

- Turn the valve off as much as possible.
- Flush the toilet.
- Take the supply line lose *from the toilet* and let it, and the toilet, drain into a bucket.
- Have towels down on the floor because it's going to get a little messy as you install the new equipment as fast as possible and hook everything back up.
- Don't be in such a rush that you cross-thread or over tighten. A little water never hurt anything.

If you're really worried get a tiny brass cap to put on the valve while you work. It's probably 3/8ths compression thread and usually found in the isle with faucet repair parts - alternatively, get a 3/8ths compression thread *plug* to put into the supply line. Both usually require a few wraps of PTFE tape to actually seal - but again we're talking minutes, so whatever: towels, a bucket, and *get 'er done*.

Comment: Thanks Mazura. I went the whole house off route! Now I’ve got everything installed. However the T adapter is leaking where the hose goes to the bidet. Slightly, enough to be a problem. Now I’m wrapping the PTFE tape around each thread and praying it fixes the leak. Cuz I have to run back out to the curb each time! Ha. If these things fail I shall be heeding your advice when the hardware store is open and I can get a few plugs. The other threads I saw on supply valves were actually what terrified me—one said you could lose a ball in the valve if overtightening a screw and then it’s leak city.

Comment: @thetallone - a very slight drip might plug itself with minerals. That's not ideal, but if you've put it together six times and all you get is a drop every 30 seconds, put a pan under it and try to wait it out.

Comment: Please, please please replace the stop valve while you have the water shut off to the house. Those valves provide a local point to stop the water for maintenance and for leaks. If something leaks in the future and *you* are not there, the person who tries to turn if off likely will not know how to quickly shut off the main... and your house is flooded.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - then they'd be breaking the rule: *know where the shut off is*. But yeah, if you've got it shut off and you have to go clean all of your aerators anyway, now's the time to swap the valve.